# Running multiple instances of a shell function parallelly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having a shell script as follows.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

myfunc() {
   #do something (call a rest service)
   sleep 300
   status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   while [ "$status" != "succeeded" ]; do
       #do something (call a rest service)
       sleep 300
       status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   done
}

a=0

while [ $a -lt 1000 ]
do
   a=`expr $a + 1`
   myfunc
done
```

In best case, above script takes at least `5*1000=5000` seconds to complete running.

Is there a way to make the `myfunc` call parallel so that we can let the while loop to spawn multiple running instances of the `myfunc`??

Note: Somehow, this script should wait until all instances of `myfunc` executions are completed.

Comment: I am not sure if bash does multi threading. You might wanna use some more sophisticated language than shell script to write this ...

Comment: `export -f myfunc; seq 1000 | xargs -P0 bash -c myfunc`

Comment: To avoid output from jobs mixing, you can iuse GNU Parallel: `export -f myfunc`, run `parallel myfunc ::: {1..1000}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could update your script as follow:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

myfunc() {
   job_id=$1
   echo "Started job ${job_id}..."

   #do something (call a rest service)
   sleep 300
   status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   while [ "$status" != "succeeded" ]; do
       #do something (call a rest service)
       sleep 300
       status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   done

   echo "Terminated job ${job_id}."
}

a=0

while [ $a -lt 1000 ]
do
   echo $a
   a=(($a + 1))
   myfunc $a &
done

wait
echo "Parallel execution terminated."
```

Comment: `a=($a + 1)` that's a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca sorry, I kept it as it is and asked a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923291/running-multiple-instances-of-a-shell-function-parallelly can you check this as well?

Answer (score 2):

Put them in background.

```
while [ $a -lt 1000 ]
do echo $a
   a=`expr $a + 1`
   myfunc &
done
wait
```

Or, in more idiomatic `bash`,

```
while (( a < 1000 ))
do echo $((a++))
   myfunc &
done
wait
```