# Running multiple instances of a shell function parallelly without mixing the output with other jobs

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having a shell script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunc() {
   #do something (call a rest service)
   sleep 300
   status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   while [ "$status" != "succeeded" ]; do
       #do something (call a rest service)
       sleep 300
       status=$(get status of the operation performed above)
   done
}

a=0

while [ $a -lt 1000 ]
do
   echo "Starting myfunc with process : $a"
   a=`expr $a + 1`
   myfunc
   echo "Finished myfunc with process : $a"
done
```

In best case, above script takes at least `5*1000=5000` seconds to complete running.

Is there a way to make the `myfunc` call parallel so that we can let the while loop to spawn multiple running instances of the `myfunc`??

In addition to that I want following conditions to be satisfied.

1. This script should wait until all instances of `myfunc` executions are completed.
2. The output of above should be like below (it should preserve the echo order).

```
    Starting myfunc with process : x
    Finished myfunc with process : x
    Starting myfunc with process : y
    Finished myfunc with process : y
    Starting myfunc with process : k
    Finished myfunc with process : k
```

It should not like below.

```
    Starting myfunc with process : x
    Starting myfunc with process : k
    Finished myfunc with process : k
    Starting myfunc with process : z
    Finished myfunc with process : x
    Finished myfunc with process : z
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forking / Multi-Threaded Processes | Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455695/forking-multi-threaded-processes-bash)

Comment: GNU Parallel does exactly this: Postpone the output until the job is done. Move the `echo` inside `myfunc`, `export -f myfunc`, run `parallel myfunc ::: {1..1000}`